# AFNetworking not working after Urban Airship notification in foreground

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, urbanairship.com

I'm using Urban Airship for push notifications and AFNetworking to get responses from the server.

When the iOS is in the active state, if a push notification comes in, I'm showing a view, tapping on which triggers the required network calls. Once the user taps on the view, AFNetworking success/error blocks aren't called.

I'm guessing this is the same issue as https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/307 Is there a fix for the same? After the time-out period, I get the following timeout message.

```
Error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1742f6b00 {NSUnderlyingError=0x17045aac0 "The request timed out.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.1.2/xxx, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.1.2/xxx, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
```

Here's the code that I'm executing:

```
[_manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"serverAddress"] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id gameCenterDetails) {
    // Response
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error %@", error.description);
}];
```

Thanks.